# error while creating streamlit webapp using google colab for basic image classification webapp

Tags: python, web-deployment, streamlit

I am trying to create a simple classification web app, referening the article -https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-an-image-classification-web-app-with-python-3753c46bb79 .
i am trying this article in Google colab env, while creating the streamlit webapp i obtained following error during running a command line -
`streamlit run rps_app.py`
ERROR

```
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7d4ea1e3639a> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import streamlit as st
      3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 from PIL import Image, ImageOps
      5 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    789                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    790                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 791                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    792 
    793             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (ipykernel 4.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('ipykernel>=5.1.2; python_version >= "3.4"'), {'pydeck'})``
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try  restart the runtime and run again? it worked for me.

Comment: it worked after restarting the runtime , but i could not find any prompt window for a web app after running the streamlite app, please guide me how to proceed ?

Comment: hello! you can try this link i think it could help you!https://gist.github.com/tuffacton/da5a9b42c0a2e9e355353689f93c84b3

Answer (score 2):

I use this source code in colab:

```
%%writefile app.py
import streamlit as st
```

Answer (score 0):

After restart the runtime and run again? it worked for me.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.